# what is best way to track user's time spent in Dynamics 365?

Tags: office365, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

we are wanting to know much time our users are spending in Dynamics 365, with as much specificity as possible. For instance, how much time are they spending working on tasks, contact records, or appointment records? Which records are they accessing the most? Does anyone have thoughts on the best way to achieve this? Perhaps creative use of the Office and Dynamics audit logs. Or are there any 3rd party integrations designed for this? Any thoughts are appreciated.

We explored using the Teams status feature (available, busy, away, etc) as a way to get insight into this information, but that does not give much information nor say what users are actually working on office or Dynamics.

Comment: There is currently no supported OOB way to achieve this, you can spend some time trying to work with all the back end tables to get these metrics but it would be extremely time consuming. I've only heard of a third party vendor that has a solution for this, but I haven't tested it myself(check out Inogics solution)

Answer (score 1):

There are some analytics dashboards available in the [Power Platform admin center](https://admin.powerplatform.microsoft.com) that will give you some of what you want.

[image: Dashboard]

Comment: This is not a complete answer, should've been a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most close solution for your requirement is to manage activities in Dynamics 365 for now

> The system automatically timestamps every activity and shows who created it. You and other people on your team can scroll through the activities to see the history as you work with a customer.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/sales/manage-activities

Additionally Microsoft Purview provides some features for audit logging:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/enable-use-comprehensive-auditing